# Bootstrap <form> height

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to have a form on my website using the Bootstrap framework, which is going fine except for the fact that Bootstrap doesn't seem to be calculating the form's height. I have a footer right after my form, in a separate div tag, but when I view the output in my browser, the footer just covers half of the form. It's like Bootstrap doesn't give the form div an automatic height.

Code: 
 https://jsfiddle.net/w2s61Lfo/

**The form is the last element in the wrapper and then the footer is the last of my body. Sorry about the messy CSS, I write messy and then go back and clean it.

Output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCfdJ.jpg

**I can't post images yet, sorry!!**

Thanks!

Comment: Without code we can't help you, sorry.

Comment: Please provide the code of your form or we cannot help you. Better will be a working example.

Comment: You shouldn't post pictures of code in the first place (that goes triple when you copy the wrong URL to your clipboard!)

Comment: How about posting the code

Comment: Put a [MCVE] **in the question itself**.

Comment: Note that you can delete your question to stop it attracting further downvotes, edit it to fix the problems with it, and then undelete it.

Comment: Haha, ok. My bad guys. I linked the wrong thing and should have used jfiddle anyways.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't show any issue at all... Your sticky footer is set correctly as expected and it doesn't overlap

Comment: @DavidChelliah In the fiddle, it looks correct, but in browser the footer continues to overlap the form.

Comment: I suspect that the overlap can only happen if your negative margin specified for **wrapper** is not equal to the height specified for your "push" div.

Comment: I just checked, wrapper is at -200px and the push is at 200px. It's as if the Bootstrap form has no height. The only space between the div above the form and the footer is the height of the push div.

Comment: @DavidChelliah I figured it out! My push div was within the container holding the form. I just brought it outside in between the container and the footer and it acted as it should have. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sticky footer is correct. Your bootstrap columns usage is wrong...

Bootstrap uses the container as just a wrapper div to control the width of you content part and also to provide a gutter around your content.

Col-xs-*, col-sm-* etc., - These are just floating elements with certain widths in percentage. Since these divs are floated, their correct heights will be calculated only when it has a "row" around it.

row - has clearfix ( CSS clear) specified in it. so that col-* height can be calculated

YOU MUST have a row around your columns

```
<div class="row">
<form class="col-xs-12"></form>
</div>
```

Here is a working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/davidsekar/qr6gecj9/1/

Comment: Yeah, that works along with the incorrect "push" placement. Thanks.